# Android: how to leave a service running after closing activities?

Tags: android, service, background, android-activity

I am writing an application which is composed of 02 components: a service running in the background and a UI to control the service, visualize data. I put them in one application, running the service in a different process inside the main activity. But when the activity is closed the service is terminated also. How can I leave it running in the background when the activity is closed?

Thank you all for giving me a clue to my problems!

Regards,

Comment: How are you starting the service? Could you please provide some code? Usually a service will run even if the activities are closed.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Here is the function called to start the service inside the activity:

void doBindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(RemoteServiceClient.this, 
                RemoteService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
...
}

Answer (score 2):

use startService instead of bindService, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#servlife

Answer (score 1):

From the Android documentation (see: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle)

The service lifecycle—from when it's created to when it's destroyed—can follow two different paths:

- **A started service**
  The service is created when another component calls startService(). The service then runs indefinitely and must stop itself by calling stopSelf(). Another component can also stop the service by calling stopService(). When the service is stopped, the system destroys it..
- **A bound service**
  The service is created when another component (a client) calls bindService(). The client then communicates with the service through an IBinder interface. The client can close the connection by calling unbindService(). Multiple clients can bind to the same service and when all of them unbind, the system destroys the service. (The service does not need to stop itself.)